# Community Toolkit.Mvvm - Where can I find an exhaustive list of field decorators

Tags: community-toolkit-mvvm

I'm trying to find an exhaustive list of available field decorators in Community Toolkit.Mvvm.

I've been able to discover the following list from a couple of YouTube videos posted by James Montemagno:
`[ObservableProperty]`
`[AlsoNotifyChangeFor()]`
`[Required]`
`[MinLength()]`
`[MaxLength()]`
`[EmailAddress]`
`[Phone]`

I'm sure there must be more, but I haven't been able to discover an exhaustive list.
I've browsed the online documentation at learn.microsoft.com and haven't found what I'm looking for.
I've even forked and downloaded the code from GitHub, but have yet to find what I'm looking for there either.

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

I have managed to discover some more by browsing further into the GitHub code:

```
[Range(#, #)]
[NotifyDataErrorInfo]
[Display(Name='xyz')]
[NotifyPropertyChangedRecipients]
[ObservableRecipient]
[Key]
[Editable(true)]
[UIHint(. . .)]
```

BUT, I shouldn't have to go picking through hundreds and hundreds of lines of code to continue to discover what I'm looking for.
Hopefully, there is a published list SOMEWHERE.
If not, could somebody please take the time to create and publish such a list?

Answer (score 1):

AHA! I discovered that most of the field decorators, or "Annotations", that I was looking for are defined in a separate NuGet "System.ComponentModel.Annotations".

The documentation at learn.microsoft.com for the namespace "System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" DOES contain a list of all of the available annotations.
See the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=net-6.0